# Whats the batch request limit for Facebooks Graph API?

Tags: facebook, batch-file, facebook-graph-api, limit, batch-processing

Does anyone know whats the limit for batch requests when using FBs graph API?
From their documentation:

> **Limit**
>
> We currently limit the number of batch requests to 20.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)

That's not clear. Is that 20 per 600 seconds? Per day? Total for one app ever?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that 20 individual requests are allowed to be batched together into a single batched request, which saves you from sending 20 individual http requests over at the same time.

Comment: Aha. One can see how it is ambiguous. I think they meant to say "We currently limit the number of batched requests to 20". Better would be: "Currently, up to 20 requests are permitted in one batch".

Comment: Now the limit is 50 requests / batch.

Answer (score 9):

It is 50 now. 50 request/batch

Comment: At the time of response. Jun 8' 12. I don't know what it is now (comment time)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than twenty (20) you can build an array and then break them into groups of 20 or less and loop them thru your PHP in one "session".   We have one app that will run 600 - 700 OG requests but it is sloooooooow, up to 300 seconds, some times, depending on FB.

Comment: Hi bill... how much time do you wait between each batch request before you send the next one?